# Using googlemaps distance matrix python api behind proxy

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3, proxy

I'm having problems getting the googlemaps distance matrix function to working behind a proxy.
Without a proxy this code works fine:

```
import googlemaps
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=googleAPIkey)    
commuteData = gmaps.distance_matrix(origins, destination, mode=mode, language=language, avoid=avoid, units=units)
```

I've tried setting the proxy like so

```
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=googleAPIkey, requests_kwargs={'proxies':"http://<proxy server>"})
```

When I step through the code the requests proxies variable seems to be set correctly, but I get the error

```
googlemaps.exceptions.TransportError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python/issues/83, the googlemaps client is really just passing that value onto requests.  Request's proxies value is intended to be a dictionary (http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#main-interface), and that dictionary should map protocol to the URL of the proxy.

So, I think you want:

```
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=googleAPIkey, requests_kwargs={'proxies':{"http":"http://<proxy server>","https":"http://<proxy_server>"})
```

(Assuming your proxy is set up so the same proxy port will work for both http and https)

Also: in general, python requests does respect the environment if you're running this from Linux or Windows (and presumably Mac); you should be able to do (outside your app, or inside if you really want via os.environ) `export http_proxy=http://proxyserver` (or http://proxyserver:3128 if not listening on 80) and then run your command without needing to hardcode the proxies in each request.

Comment: That did it, thanks. I hate spending hours on a problem only to find out it was due to a simple syntax error.

Comment: re: python and proxy's. Yes, python does appear to be honoring the environment variables when I run from a command line. However I do most of my development in Eclipse - PyDev and I've had all sorts of proxy issues with it. I know my env vars are set correctly, and I configure the same proxy setting in Eclipse's Network Connections. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.  I've found the safest option is to add the proxy config to my code.